# Problem related to change notifier provider in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I am getting an error when using `changenotifierprovider` in my flutter project.

Error:

**'MyUser' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier?' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier?'.**

Class:

```
class SettingsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  static Widget getWidget() {
    return new Provider(
      create: (_) => MyUser(uid: ''),
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(  <-- here **ChangeNotifierProvider**
          create: (BuildContext context) => MyUser(uid: ''),
          builder: (_, _) => SettingsForm()),
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add `with ChangeNotifier` to `MyUser` class.

```
class MyUser with ChangeNotifier {}
```

Comment: it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

In the class MyUser, add

```
extends ChangeNotifier
```

Such that it'll look like

```
class MyUser extends ChangeNotifier {}
```